# MongoDB - remove unique documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, filter

I need to remove documents those are unique with a field value. I am running a query to find out documents by some conditions. Here is the query -

```
db.contents.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        $or: [
            {
                $and: [
                    { widgetId: new ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2") },
                    { value: 'Yes' }
                ]
            },
            {
                $and: [
                    { widgetId: new ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9") },
                    {
                        value: "20"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
])
```

I get following documents from `contents` collection after running the query -

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId("648d50d3221f77c425aac162"),
  label: 'Featured Product',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d50d3221f77c425aac146"),
  slug: 'featured-product',
  value: 'Yes',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2")
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("648d5131221f77c425aac1b9"),
  label: 'Featured Product',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d5131221f77c425aac1b0"),
  slug: 'featured-product',
  value: 'Yes',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2")
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("648d5199221f77c425aac223"),
  label: 'Featured Product',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d5199221f77c425aac21a"),
  slug: 'featured-product',
  value: 'Yes',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2")
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac28b"),
  label: 'Discount',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac284"),
  slug: 'discount',
  value: '20',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9")
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac28d"),
  label: 'Featured Product',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac284"),
  slug: 'featured-product',
  value: 'Yes',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2")
}]
```

Now, in the same query I need to remove all documents those have unique `itemId`. So, the result output should be -

```
[{
  _id: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac28b"),
  label: 'Discount',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac284"),
  slug: 'discount',
  value: '20',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d4111ae1b9fb2af57f8f9")
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac28d"),
  label: 'Featured Product',
  itemId: ObjectId("648d51d1221f77c425aac284"),
  slug: 'featured-product',
  value: 'Yes',
  widgetId: ObjectId("648d461dae1b9fb2af57fbb2")
}]
```

I think, I need to apply `filter` to perform the task but can't find out a solution. There might be other approaches to that.

Comment: Do you want to remove the documents from database or just from the output?

Comment: Just from the output @biorubenfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we might be able to accomplish that by using below query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     // grouping based on itemId ;
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$itemId",
      count: {
        $count: {}
      }
    }
  },
    //  remove those who have count < 2 (unique elements)
  {
    $match: {
      "count": {
        $gte: 2
      },
      
    }
  },
   // populate documents
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "itemId",
      as: "fromItems"
    }
  },
   // level up 'fromItems'
  {
    $unwind: "$fromItems"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$fromItems"
    }
  }
])
```

---

The above code runs in 3 phases,

First we perform grouping of documents, in order to observe which one of them are unique. We then remove those documents.

In the second phase, we have a collection of non-unique documents but with no data but only their ids, we need to populate them. So, we then perform join on them with itself (using `$lookup`).

Finally, we just move `fromItems` a level up, effectively making it a document instead of an embedded document.

You can test this out to see if its working or not.

Comment: The logic is exactly the one I am looking for, but when populating documents after match count is greater than 2, then the query does not work.

// populate documents
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "collection",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "itemId",
      as: "fromItems"
    }
  },

Comment: @user3384985 If its possible, can you share a larger dataset to test my query on. And I also don't understand how it is not working?

Comment: The query is working fine in the application. But i got the issue when I tried to execute the query in MongoDB Compass Shell. The shell got hanged when I executed the query. Still don't know what is the actual issue.

Comment: @user3384985 dunno, maybe we need a more efficient query.

Comment: Please let me know if you have better solution. @deepanshu